# Bootstrap 5 multi level dropdown

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been playing around with this multilevel dropdown for Bootstrap 5 but it only seems to work with the beta release. For some reason in latest Bootstrap release it doesn't close the previous menu. So if you have 2 multilevel dropdown and click on 1 and then the other, they both stay open. Does anyone know how to fix it to work with latest Bootstrap 5?

https://jsfiddle.net/dallaslu/mvk4uhzL/

```
(function($bs) {
    const CLASS_NAME = 'has-child-dropdown-show';
$bs.Dropdown.prototype.toggle = function(_orginal) {
    return function() {
        document.querySelectorAll('.' + CLASS_NAME).forEach(function(e) {
            e.classList.remove(CLASS_NAME);
        });
        let dd = this._element.closest('.dropdown').parentNode.closest('.dropdown');
        for (; dd && dd !== document; dd = dd.parentNode.closest('.dropdown')) {
            dd.classList.add(CLASS_NAME);
        }
        return _orginal.call(this);
    }
}($bs.Dropdown.prototype.toggle);

document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown').forEach(function(dd) {
    dd.addEventListener('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
        if (this.classList.contains(CLASS_NAME)) {
            this.classList.remove(CLASS_NAME);
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        if(e.clickEvent && e.clickEvent.composedPath().some(el=>el.classList && el.classList.contains('dropdown-toggle'))){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        e.stopPropagation(); // do not need pop in multi level mode
    });
});

// for hover
function getDropdown(element) {
    return $bs.Dropdown.getInstance(element) || new $bs.Dropdown(element);
}

document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-hover, .dropdown-hover-all .dropdown').forEach(function(dd) {
    dd.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
        let toggle = e.target.querySelector(':scope>[data-bs-toggle="dropdown"]');
        if (!toggle.classList.contains('show')) {
            getDropdown(toggle).toggle();
        }
    });
    dd.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) {
        let toggle = e.target.querySelector(':scope>[data-bs-toggle="dropdown"]');
        if (toggle.classList.contains('show')) {
            getDropdown(toggle).toggle();
        }
    });
});
})(bootstrap);
```

Thx